# assigning the returning function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and I saw code like this.

```
<button onclick="this.onClickDoSmth">Click me</button> 

onClickDoSmth = () => {
let a = this.clicked();
a();
}

clicked = () => {
console.log("test"); 
}
```

What's the difference of replacing the expression for "a" to

```
onClickDoSmth = () => {
this.clicked();
}
```

Comment: See “normal function vs arrow function” - many duplicates. Also search for “this in javascript”.

Comment: There is no function declaration in the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 0):

First a correction is required. It should be `let a = this.clicked;` instead of `let a = this.clicked()`. The former means you're assigning the returning function to the variable `a` and executing it later with `a()`. So if you do this way, there's no difference.

```
onClickDoSmth = () => {
    let a = this.clicked; //This has to be corrected
    a();
    }

    clicked = () => {
    console.log("test"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the former version **received something** from the function while the latter one doesn't.


This means the value of `a` receive what `this.clicked` function ***return***. `this.clicked` must return a function so that it can be called by `a()` afterward

```
onClickDoSmth = () => {
    let a = this.clicked();
    a();
}
```

This means `onClickDoSmth` is a function. After it has been executed, run `this.clicked`

```
onClickDoSmth = () => {
   this.clicked();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The former uses assigns a function and calls that variable if you want to reuse again. The latter just calls the function immediately. Both will achieve the same output.